# Relative to what are regular expressions evaluated in java.util.Scanner?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I noticed the following weird behavior that I can't explain:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var scanner = new Scanner("ab");

    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));  // output: a
    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));  // output: b
  }
}
```

but

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var scanner = new Scanner("ab");

    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));  // output: a
    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("^.")); // output: null
  }
}
```

I don't understand how the second snippet is any different from the first one.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `^` matches the beginning of a line but this doesn't seem to be the case, since:

1. `a` at the beginning of the line matches,
2. `a` at the beginning of the input matches, and
3. `b` at the position of the scanner matches.

If the regular expression it's not evaluated relative to the position of the scanner, what is it evaluated relative to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all there, just poorly documented. Here is how `findInLine` is implemented:

> ```java
> public String findInLine(Pattern pattern) {
>     // omitted: validate parameters
>     // omitted: ensure the internal buffer is large enough
>
>     return findWithinHorizon(pattern, horizonForLine);
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>Source: [java/util/Scanner.java](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l1698)</sub>

Here is what the documentation has to say about `findWithinHorizon`:

> [...] The scanner treats the horizon as a transparent, non-anchoring bound [...].
>
> <sub>Source: [java.util.Scanner#findWithinHorizon(java.util.regex.Pattern,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon(java.util.regex.Pattern,int))</sub>

and about anchoring bounds:

> [...] Without anchoring bounds, the boundaries of this matcher's region will not match anchors such as `^` and `$`. [...]
>
> <sub>Source: [java.util.regex.Matcher##useAnchoringBounds(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#useAnchoringBounds(boolean))</sub>

Here is how `findWithinHorizon` is implemented:

> ```java
> public String findWithinHorizon(Pattern pattern, int horizon) {
>     // omitted: validate parameters
>
>     while (true) {
>         if (findPatternInBuffer(pattern, horizon)) {
>             matchValid = true;
>             return matcher.group();
>         }
>
>         // omitted: check if more input is required
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>Source: [java/util/Scanner.java](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l1780)</sub>

Here is how `findPatternInBuffer` is implemented:

> ```java
> private boolean findPatternInBuffer(Pattern pattern, int horizon) {
>     // omitted: calculating search limit
>
>     matcher.region(position, searchLimit);
>
>     // omitted: matching pattern
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>[java/util/Scanner.java](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Scanner.java#l1078)</sub>

That's why the second pattern didn't match. The regular expression only searched ahead of the cursor, but didn't consider `^` applicable for the cursor position. It is however applicable to the beginning of the input, therefor the first pattern matched.

That doesn't mean that every regular expression with `^` will fail, a positive look behind will work:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var scanner = new Scanner("ab");

    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));        // output: a
    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("(?<=^.).")); // output: b
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding both code snippets, the scanner has only past `a` not the full line. To go to the next line you need to call `scanner.nextLine()`.

> The findInLine(Pattern pattern) method of `java.util.Scanner` class
>   tries to find the next occurrence of the specified pattern ignoring
>   delimiters. If the pattern is found before the next line separator,
>   **the scanner advances past the input that matched and returns the
>   string that matched the pattern**. If no such pattern is detected in the
>   input up to the next line separator, then null is returned and the
>   scanner’s position is unchanged.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-findinline-method-in-java-with-examples/

**Examples:**

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("abcde\nx");
    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));    // output: a
    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));    // output: b
```

Here scanner has matched the first character (a) and moved to b that is still on the same line.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("abcde\nx");
    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));     // output: a
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));     // output: x
```

Here, the scanner works the same way as before but I have moved past first line separator.

Comment: Not exactly, Java treats them differently based on stream sources.

Comment: ^ means start of a line. If you read my answer carefully, you will understand why.

Comment: `System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("."));` Here scanner matches first character that's `a` and moves past `a` not to the second line  that's why `System.out.println(scanner.findInLine("^."));` returns null.